# What pattern to use in preg_match to get value from string

Tags: php, preg-match

I have two strings

First One:

```
Date: Sat, 13 Jun 2015 13:26:05 +0100
Subject: Changing the balance: +50,00 CZK
Dear client,
```

Second One:

```
Date: Sat, 14 Jun 2015 14:58:05 +0100
Subject: Changing the balance: +75,00 CZK
Dear client,
```

And I really don't know what pattern to use if I want to get the number of CZKs from these strings. I need integer `50` from first string and integer `75` from second string (just integer not decimal with `,00`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can really be as simple or as complex as you need it to be. In it's simplest form, you could look for a pattern that reads:

number.comma.number.space.CZK

this can be written as:

[0-9]+,[0-9]+\sCZK

[0-9] is a range, between 0-9 (number). The plus character means that at least 1 number is required. If you wanted to make this EXACTLY 2 numbers you could change [0-9]+ for [0-9]{2}

, is a comma...

[0-9]+ is another number (at least 1)

\s is a space

CZK is the string you're wanting to end with

You can expand upon this as you wish. Here is a working example: http://regexr.com/3baog

*Edit*:

If you wish to capture the 50 / 75, you need to wrap parenthesis around the part you're after, eg:

`([0-9]+),[0-9]+\sCZK`

Comment: @UareBugged the above regex will select all things starting from integer upto the end of CZK, whereas your question states that you need only integer, which is what the regex in my answer do. Have a look at that demo. If you are interested in selecting everything, change your question.

Comment: That's a good point - I failed to mention the capture groups (). If you want to extract the 50 or 75 you would write it as so:

`([0-9]+),[0-9]+\sCZK`

Answer (score 0):

Use positive lookahead to select the integer part of number before `CZK`

```
\d+(?=,\d*\s*CZK)
```

Explanation for the above regex can be seen from this [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oM3nD9/1)

If you want to select the sign `+` or `-`, then you can add `[+-]?` at the beginning.